# Dual tunnel OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

Pretty sure the answer is no, but I cannot determine how to confirm this (I am having trouble coming up with keywords to search for).

Situation: I have a Linux (Debian) OpenVPN server which I need to connect to in two ways:

1. Full tunnel
2. Split tunnel which allows the client to browse their home directory and have ssh access.

I do not want to open the ssh up to the public due to security risks; as of now, the server only listens for local addresses (VPN clients).

Question: Can I achieve this using only one OpenVPN server session and modifying the client configs or must I have two separate OpenVPN sessions running (one for full tunnel access and one for split-tunnel access)?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to restrict ssh access to the client node for public.

You can firewall your client / server using iptables.

## iptables

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 10.8.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

It will allow ssh connections over specifict network (vpn in your case) only and block ssh from all other network.

## TCP wrapper

You can use TCP Wrapper . TCP wrapper uses 2 files, /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny

Edit `/etc/hosts.allow` and add your subnet

```
sshd : 10.8.0.
```

Edit `/etc/hosts.deny` , and deny all

```
ALL : ALL
```

## SSH configuration

You can set several options in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. One is `AllowUsers`.

```
AllowUsers you@10.8.0.0/16
```